# Generar número de ID consecutivo en Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

lo que estoy intentando hacer es que por cada registro que se complete se genere un número de ID consecutivo ascendente. Para esto, seguí un tutorial y tengo el siguiente código:

```
function generarID() {

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Respuestas de formulario 1');
   var ultimaFila = hoja.getLastRow();
   var idConsecutivo = ultimaFila -1;
   hoja.getRange(ultimaFila, 1).setValue(idConsecutivo);

}
```

Ya le di en ejecutar y no me aparece ningún error. También ya le puse el trigger, pero nada; ya me mandé varias pruebas y aunque sí me salen esos registros prueba en mi base de datos, el ID no se genera. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o qué me está faltando?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so].  Falta información.  Cuando dices "ya le puse el trigger" ¿ a qué trigger te refieres? ¿ que pasos seguiste para poner dicho trigger? ¿Está tu hoja de cálculo vinculada a un formulario de Google? ¿Dónde se debería generar el ID?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. GoogleSheets son hojas de cálculo, no bases de datos. Además, tu código actual, aun funcionando, podría generar duplicados si en algún momento se borra algún registro, y se te rompe la integridad de datos. Te recomiendo encarecidamente usar otra app para esto. Y si insistes en hacerlo en Google Sheets, mejor que el ID sea el valor máximo de la columna + 1, para evitar posibles duplicados en el futuro.

Comment: El "trigger" es el activador que ligué para generar el ID; en mi caso, el activador que puse fue llenar formulario; de tal forma que cuando un usuario conteste el formulario, se genere el ID. El ID debe generarse en la hoja de cálculo llamada "Respuestas de formulario 1". Y los pasos que seguí fueron: escribir el código en el script, desplegar la sección de "Activadores", dar click en añadir activador, y seleccionar la función a ejecutar "Generar ID".